# Passing react url params to src="" of audio HTML tag

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a react app that will eventually play out a station ident. All the files are given a definitive file name and I will link to each file and then want to pass the url parameter "name" to a page and have it load that file.

Inside my player file (Player.jsx):

```
const Player = ( { match } ) => {

const name = match.params.name;

return (
    <>
        <h1>This is the player for {name} file.</h1>
        <audio href="../../public/Audio/{name}.mp3" />
    </>
);
}
```

I'm looking to get the url which I've linked to into the name param, which it does as it outputs the H1 tag correctly but i don't know how to get it inside a src="".